# Reading files from a folder processing them line wise and writing to separate files in another folder

Tags: java, file-io

I have a folder with several files that have data in it on which I need to run my Named Entity Recognizer. I want to open each file and process it line by line and write the results to a corresponding file in the Results folder. I wrote some code but it seems to do nothing at all:

```
File file = new File(folderPath);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for(File f: files){
             String name = String.valueOf(increase);
             File resultsFile = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/Data_And_Sentences/Results/File" + name + ".txt");

             BufferedReader br = null;
            try
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(f));

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String line;
            try
            {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                     while(resultsFile.exists()){
                          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(resultsFile.getAbsoluteFile());
                          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                          HashMap<String, Vector<String>> neMap = identifyNER(line);


                          for(String type : neMap.keySet())
                          {

                              bw.write(type + ": " + neMap.get(type)+"\t");
                              bw.newLine();

                          }

                          if(bw!=null)
                              bw.flush();
                            bw.close();

                            increase++;
                            name = String.valueOf(increase);
                            resultsFile = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/Data_And_Sentences/Results/File" + name + ".txt");
                            continue;
                     }

                        if(!resultsFile.exists()) {

                            resultsFile.createNewFile();
                            continue;

                        }
```

Comment: [Try to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Where does the execution stop? Which line of code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @defaultlocale Thanks for the comment. I was actually inspired by the blog post you shared and got down to debugging my own program and made it work! A big part of the problem always is fear and self-doubt specially when you are a novice at something...you feel you can't do it yourself and need expert help. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great! Now, I guess, you can post an answer to your question here.